# Make internal classes not used outside a library

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resharper

Due to the disappointing fact of having public as default modificator for `classes`/`structs`/`enums` in both `Visual Studio` and `Resharper`, the solution I am working on right now has a huge amount of public classes which are not used outside a library they are defined in. So I want to make all those classes internal. And I don't want to do it manually.

Is there any way to automate this task? In general I want to have something like `Adjust visibility` refactoring (similar to Resharper's `Adjust namespaces`).

Comment: Wouldn't a search & replace of "public class" just about cover it (for classes, anyway)?

Comment: @Moose, it is what I will do if don't find any automatic approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find-and-replace using regular expressions. For example in Visual Studio 2012, the following will do what you want (after you enable regular expression matching in the search box):

```
public (.*(class|enum|struct))
```

Replace with:

```
internal $1
```

After that you can use the class view to show only public members and do those that are left manually.

---

For Visual Studio 2010 the syntax is different. I think it is like this, but could not test it:

```
public {:.*(class|enum|struct)}
```

Replace with:

```
internal \1
```

You can find [more information here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

`public` is not the default access modifier in C#. According to the [documentations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) `internal` is the default access modifier if you do specify any.

If you explicitly set the public access modifier then I think its best to review your code manually and choose the best access modifier.

Comment: You are right. But I was talking about Visual Studio and Resharper (as their templates use public by default), not about C#

Comment: You should review your code and force your developers to take care about access modifiers whenever they create classes/methods/...

Comment: Sure. But how should it help in the described situation?

Comment: Just an idea: Set every public access modifier to internal and build your library. Now you should get lots of compilation errors in the projects using the library. Go back to your library and set the access modifiers to public where necessary.